# AVAudioEngine audio stops when switching the audio output device

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I have this simple Swift code that uses an AVAudioEngine + AVAudioPlayerNode to play an audio file on loop.

When I start the app the audio plays on the laptop speakers. If I switch my computer's output to a HomePod mini, the audio on the laptop stops but never plays on the HomePod mini (the mini also doesn't light up).

If I stop the app and run it again - the audio plays on the HomePod mini. If I switch back to the laptop - the audio stops until I restart the app, etc.

It seems the problem is with switching the output device during playback, but I cannot understand how to fix this. Below is my code:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Attach audio player
        engine.attach(player)
        
        // Load audio file
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sheep1.m4a", ofType: nil)!
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)
        
        // Load the audio buffer
        let fileFormat = file.processingFormat
        let fileFrameCount = UInt32(file.length)
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: fileFormat, frameCapacity: fileFrameCount)
        try! file.read(into: buffer!, frameCount: fileFrameCount)
        
        // Connect to the mixer
        let mainMixer = engine.mainMixerNode
        engine.connect(player, to: mainMixer, format: file.processingFormat)

        // Start the engine
        try! engine.start()
        
        // Play the audio
        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer!, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW - The code you have above works for me under macOS 10.15.7 when I play a .mp3 file to an Airplay (1, not 2) device (I don't have a HomePod) after starting playback to the laptop speakers. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: However, if I compile this under 11.2.2 I see the behavior you are seeing and errors in the console like:           2021-04-02 16:38:51.304423-0700 testSound[1500:30200] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:820   couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2021-04-02 16:38:51.885353-0700 testSound[1500:30821]  AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0

Comment: Take a look at `AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange` in the documentation which suggests that the playback will be stopped when this notification is sent.  It's sent in 11.2.2 but not in 10.15.7.    I tried restarting playback there, but haven't been able to get this to work (yet).

Comment: I just heard back from Apple tech support they suggested observing for that notification too and that seems to be working fine on Big Sur. The contraption is that you have to recreate your whole audio mixer setup as all nodes are detached when the output device changes.

Comment: So 10.15.7 is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard back from Apple tech support and as Dad commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923293/avaudioengine-audio-stops-when-switching-the-audio-output-device#comment118303540_66923293) when the audio engine configuration changes there is a `AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange` notification being sent.

At this point the nodes are detached and the audio setup needs to be re-constructed and the engine restarted to start playing audio on the new output device.

I'm including below the complete AppDelegate that tests the original premise of the question. On starting the app I'm calling both `setupAudio()` to load the audio and `playAudio()` to start the playback.

Additionally each time the audio engine configuration changes I'm calling `playAudio()` to restart the playback:

```swift
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    // Load audio file
    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sheep1.m4a", ofType: nil)!))
    var buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Attach audio player
        setupAudio()
        playAudio()
    }
    
    /// Call this only ONCE
    func setupAudio() {
        engine.attach(player)

        // Load the audio buffer
        let fileFormat = file.processingFormat
        let fileFrameCount = UInt32(file.length)
        buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: fileFormat, frameCapacity: fileFrameCount)
        file.framePosition = .zero
        try! file.read(into: buffer!, frameCount: fileFrameCount)

        // Observe for changes in the audio engine configuration
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
           selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
           name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange,
           object: nil
        )
    }
    
    /// Call this every time you want to restart audio
    func playAudio() {
        // Connect to the mixer
        let mainMixer = engine.mainMixerNode
        engine.connect(player, to: mainMixer, format: file.processingFormat)

        // Start the engine
        try! engine.start()
        
        // Play the audio
        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
        player.play()
    }
    
    @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
        playAudio()
    }
}
```

This code works for me on Big Sur.

Comment: Are you sure you have to schedule a new buffer and play it? That resets your audio state, you should be able to hear the audio play from where it was interrupted.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it and without the schedule no audio is being played. If you want to continue from where you were I guess you have to play with the player position property but for my case resetting the position is ok.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reply you got from AppleDev. 

Something doesn’t sound quite right because the documentation for that event says “ The nodes remain attached and connected with previously set formats.”  Only the output node should need to change (if anything).  And this is a change in behavior over 10.15 which seems odd.